# In jQuery, does creating an element with CSS method without a unit give the element a default value?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the following line of Code to create an anchor link:

```
$('<a>').css("width", 100)
```

The `<a>` has width of 100. However, I did not give 100 a unit. Once the element is created and added to DOM, will it be given a width of 100px?

Comment: Note you can also do `.width(100)` or `width(100,'px')` or another such as `.width(6.25,"rem")` (which is `100/16` where most browsers default to `16px`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss why is the "100/16" equivalent to 16px in this case?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment `6.25 = 100/16` and `1rem` defaults to `16px` in most browsers SO, `6.25rem` = `100px` by default- hope that makes more sense (note that you can override in CSS the `rem` to by what you want also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/):

> When a number is passed as the value, jQuery will convert it to a string and add px to the end of that string. If the property requires units other than px, convert the value to a string and add the appropriate units before calling the method.

The answer to your question is yes, it will be given a width of 100px.